# __FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.app.earth.env.EarthDS]"]}?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss

I am trying to deploy my `JAVA EE7` application. I have `EntityManagerProducer` as

```
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;

@Startup
@Singleton
public class PersistenceEntityManagerProducer {
    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "earth")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Produces
    @PersistenceEntityManager
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }
}
```

and my `CrudService` as

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class CrudService {
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public CrudService() {
    }

    @Inject
    public CrudService(@PersistenceEntityManager @Nonnull final EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    @Nonnull
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    @Nonnull
    public <T> T create(@Nonnull final T entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.refresh(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    @Nullable
    public <T> T find(final long id, final Class<T> classType) {
        return entityManager.find(classType, id);
    }

    public <T> void delete(@Nonnull final T entity) {
        entityManager.remove(entity);
    }
}
```

My `persistence.xml` looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="earth" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:app/env/EarthDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.lock.timeout" value="5000"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I try to deploy my application using `maven-cargo-plugin` and `pom.xml` looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>multi-persistence</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.learner</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>integration</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.learner</groupId>
            <artifactId>services</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.180</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.10.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
            <version>10.11.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <maven.cargo.version>1.4.8</maven.cargo.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.carlspring.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>derby-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <port>1527</port>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-derby</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-derby</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.cargo.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <container>
                        <containerId>wildfly8x</containerId>
                        <dependencies combine.children="append">
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
                                <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
                                <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </container>
                    <configuration>
                        <properties>
                            <cargo.servlet.port>9090</cargo.servlet.port>
                            <properties>
                                <cargo.datasource.datasource.derby>
                                    cargo.datasource.driver=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver|
                                    cargo.datasource.url=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/earth;create=true|
                                    cargo.datasource.jndi=app/env/EarthDS|
                                    cargo.datasource.username=APP|
                                    cargo.datasource.password=nonemptypassword
                                </cargo.datasource.datasource.derby>
                            </properties>
                            <!--<properties>
                                <cargo.datasource.datasource.h2>
                                    cargo.datasource.driver=org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource|
                                    cargo.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:earth|
                                    cargo.datasource.jndi=jdbc/EarthDS|
                                    cargo.datasource.username=sa|
                                    cargo.datasource.password=sa
                                </cargo.datasource.datasource.h2>
                            </properties>-->
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                    <deployables>
                        <deployable>
                            <groupId>com.learner</groupId>
                            <artifactId>services</artifactId>
                            <type>war</type>
                            <properties>
                                <context>earth</context>
                            </properties>
                        </deployable>
                    </deployables>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-container</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-container</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I run my application, I see error as

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building integration 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ integration ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/harit/Box Sync/code/idea/java-ee-multiple-persistence/integration/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ integration ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/harit/Box Sync/code/idea/java-ee-multiple-persistence/integration/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ integration ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ integration ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/harit/Box Sync/code/idea/java-ee-multiple-persistence/integration/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ integration ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ integration ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ integration ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/harit/Box Sync/code/idea/java-ee-multiple-persistence/integration/target/integration-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- derby-maven-plugin:1.8:start (start-derby) @ integration ---
[INFO] Initializing Derby server control for localhost/127.0.0.1
[INFO] Starting the Derby server ...
Sat Sep 20 09:50:56 PDT 2014 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.10.1.1 - (1458268) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527
[INFO] Derby ping-pong: [OK]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.8:start (start-container) @ integration ---
[INFO] [2.ContainerStartMojo] Resolved container artifact org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-core-container-wildfly:jar:1.4.8 for container wildfly8x
[INFO] You did not specify a container home nor any installer. CARGO will automatically download your container's binaries from [http://download.jboss.org/wildfly/8.0.0.Final/wildfly-8.0.0.Final.tar.gz].
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Parsed JBoss version = [8.x]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] WildFly 8.x starting...
[INFO] [neLocalConfiguration] Configuring JBoss using the [standalone] server configuration
[INFO] [stalledLocalDeployer] Deploying [/Users/harit/Box Sync/code/idea/java-ee-multiple-persistence/integration/target/cargo/configurations/wildfly8x/tmp/cargo/earth.war] to [/Users/harit/Box Sync/code/idea/java-ee-multiple-persistence/integration/target/cargo/configurations/wildfly8x/deployments]...
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=48m; support was removed in 8.0
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:04,293 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.0.Final
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:04,692 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.0.Final
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:04,799 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015899: WildFly 8.0.0.Final "WildFly" starting
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:06,727 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:06,769 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO version 3.2.0.Final
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:06,785 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.2.0.Final
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:06,940 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.0.Final
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:07,008 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:07,031 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:07,035 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS012615: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:07,039 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:07,086 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.20.Final
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:07,128 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:07,301 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:07,303 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.0.0.Final starting
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:07,305 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.0.0.Final starting
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:07,385 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.1.3.Final)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:07,419 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:07,634 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:07,650 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:07,927 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) JBAS017527: Creating file handler for path /Users/harit/Box Sync/code/idea/java-ee-multiple-persistence/integration/target/cargo/installs/wildfly-8.0.0.Final/wildfly-8.0.0.Final/welcome-content
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:08,262 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS017525: Started server default-server.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:08,323 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS017531: Host default-host starting
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:08,673 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017519: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on /0.0.0.0:9090
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:08,971 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /Users/harit/Box Sync/code/idea/java-ee-multiple-persistence/integration/target/cargo/configurations/wildfly8x/deployments
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:08,981 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "cargocpc.war" (runtime-name: "cargocpc.war")
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:08,981 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "earth.war" (runtime-name: "earth.war")
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:09,256 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:09,710 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.2.3.Final
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:10,083 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for earth
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:10,327 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017534: Registered web context: /cargocpc
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:10,350 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "earth.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"earth.war#earth\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.app.earth.env.EarthDS]"]}
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:10,390 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) JBAS018559: Deployed "earth.war" (runtime-name : "earth.war")
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:10,391 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) JBAS018559: Deployed "cargocpc.war" (runtime-name : "cargocpc.war")
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:10,395 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]       service jboss.naming.context.java.app.earth.env.EarthDS (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."earth.war#earth".__FIRST_PHASE__] 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] WildFly 8.x started on port [9090]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- derby-maven-plugin:1.8:stop (stop-derby) @ integration ---
[INFO] Initializing Derby server control for localhost/127.0.0.1
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:10,449 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:10,449 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:10,450 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: WildFly 8.0.0.Final "WildFly" started (with errors) in 6995ms - Started 262 of 318 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 92 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
[ERROR] Derby system shutdown.
Sat Sep 20 09:51:10 PDT 2014 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.10.1.1 - (1458268) shutdown
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:10,670 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment earth.war (runtime-name: earth.war) in 33ms
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:10,744 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018558: Undeployed "earth.war" (runtime-name: "earth.war")
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:10,745 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]       service jboss.persistenceunit."earth.war#earth".__FIRST_PHASE__ (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."earth.war".POST_MODULE] 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 
[INFO] Derby has stopped!
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.8:stop (stop-container) @ integration ---
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] WildFly 8.x is stopping...
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.3.0.Final
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] WARN: can't find jboss-cli.xml. Using default configuration values.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO version 3.2.0.Final
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.2.0.Final
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 4.0.0.Final
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:14,555 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 3) JBAS014774: Service status report
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] JBAS014776:    Newly corrected services:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]       service jboss.naming.context.java.app.earth.env.EarthDS (no longer required)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]       service jboss.persistenceunit."earth.war#earth".__FIRST_PHASE__ (no longer required)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:14,575 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS017535: Unregistered web context: /cargocpc
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFO  [org.jboss.as.cli.CommandContext] 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFO  [org.jboss.as.cli.CommandContext] The connection to the controller has been closed as the result of the shutdown operation.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] The connection to the controller has been closed as the result of the shutdown operation.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFO  [org.jboss.as.cli.CommandContext] (Although the command prompt will wrongly indicate connection until the next line is entered)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] (Although the command prompt will wrongly indicate connection until the next line is entered)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:14,623 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS017532: Host default-host stopping
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:14,626 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010409: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFO  [org.jboss.as.cli.CommandContext] {"outcome" => "success"}
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] {"outcome" => "success"}
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:14,639 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010418: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = h2
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:14,640 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017521: Undertow HTTP listener default suspending
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:14,641 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017520: Undertow HTTP listener default stopped, was bound to /0.0.0.0:9090
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:14,643 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017506: Undertow 1.0.0.Final stopping
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:14,691 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.3.Final
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:14,768 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment cargocpc.war (runtime-name: cargocpc.war) in 201ms
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 09:51:14,775 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015950: WildFly 8.0.0.Final "WildFly" stopped in 207ms
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] WildFly 8.x is stopped
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ integration ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/harit/Box Sync/code/idea/java-ee-multiple-persistence/integration/target/integration-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /Users/harit/.m2/repository/com/learner/integration/1.0-SNAPSHOT/integration-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /Users/harit/Box Sync/code/idea/java-ee-multiple-persistence/integration/pom.xml to /Users/harit/.m2/repository/com/learner/integration/1.0-SNAPSHOT/integration-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong ?

Answer (score 6):

You needs to configure your datasource in your standalone.xml or create a -ds.xml datasource file in your project like explains in Jboss documentation or in mastertheboss page.
For example: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-datasource/jboss-as-7-deployable-datasources

You need to put to the datasource the name:

> java:app/env/EarthDS

because you defined it on persistence.xml:

> java:app/env/EarthDS

If prefers define your datasource in your standalone.xml. Here is an example:

```
     <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:app/env/EarthDS" pool-name="EarthDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                <driver>h2</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>sa</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
```

Note: This examples are compatibles with Jboss AS7/Wildfly .

Answer (score 1):

You can create a datasource thru the CLI (command line interface)
This is how I do it my JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/EarthDS" pool-name="EarthDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:MYDB</connection-url>
                <connection-property name="defaultNChar">
                    true
                </connection-property>
                <driver>ojdbc6.jar</driver>
                <new-connection-sql>alter session set current_schema=foobar</new-connection-sql>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>20</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>300</max-pool-size>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>username</user-name>
                    <password>passwd</password>
                </security>
                <timeout>
                    <idle-timeout-minutes>15</idle-timeout-minutes>
                </timeout>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
```

Answer (score -3):

The error message is pretty clear:

[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]       service jboss.naming.context.java.app.earth.env.EarthDS (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."earth.war#earth".**FIRST_PHASE**] 
[

Do you have the data source created ?

Comment: The data source can be created as explained at https://developer.jboss.org/message/625062

Comment: This answer isn't helpful in anyway.